# Gather my users selections from a select menu aswell as the correct answer

Tags: javascript, html

Basically the code will generate a french word, The code will then generate a select menu with 6 english words. The user then guesses what is the correct translation! **What I'm trying to do now is gather the users guessed** `<option>` **and the correct** `<option>`to go with that guess into parralel arrays so I can then display there guesses (with the correct answer next to it) at the end of the code.

### I've partly got it too work, It will store the first and only the first select menu option and answer into each of the arrays, It will not store the next 5 questions

#### Please check my latest fiddle, Observe that it will store the first q and a.

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesw1/w8p7b6p3/8/

So basically only the first French word, English translation and the first Guess they made will store into the array.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="header">
                <h1>James' Translation Guessing Game</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="main">
            <div class="bg"></div>
                <h2 id="display" style="color:rgba(204,51,204,1);">Guess what the generated french word translates to in English!</h2>
            <br />
                <h2 id="numGuess">Question #</h2 >
        <div align="center" class="frenchWord" style="position:">
             <div style="background-color:rgba(51,51,51,0.5);border-radius:4px 10px 2px;"align="center"  id="generatedWord"></div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div align="center" id="output"></div>
        <button type="button" style='opacity:0.5' id="submitAns" onClick="translate();">Check</button>
        <input type="button" value="New Game" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
             <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#generatedWord").animate({
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    margin: "40px 0px 100px 0px",
                    width: "20%",
                    padding: "30px",
                }, 1500 );
});
</script>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>James Wainwright</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var
RanNumbers = new Array(6),
    foreignWords = ['un', 'deux', 'trois', 'quatre', 'cinq', 'six', 'sept', 'huit', 'neuf', 'dix', 'onze', 'douze', 'treize', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'seize', 'dix-sept', 'dix-huit', 'dix-neuf', 'vingt', 'vingt et un', 'vingt-deux', 'vingt-trois', 'vingt-quatre', 'vingt-cinq', 'vingt-six', 'vingt-sept', 'vingt-huit', 'vingt-neuf', 'trente'],
    translate = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty', 'twenty-one', 'twenty-two', 'twenty-three', 'twenty-four', 'twenty-five', 'twenty-six', 'twenty-seven', 'twenty-eight', 'twenty-nine', 'thirty'],
    number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30)),
    output = '',
    correctAns = translate[number];

//Generate random numbers to pick the available answers
function wordGen() {
    for (var h = 0; h < RanNumbers.length; h++) {
        var temp = 0;
        do {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
        } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
        RanNumbers[h] = temp;

    }
}

//Call the previous function
wordGen();
/*var selectOptions = new Array(translate[RanNumbers[0]], translate[RanNumbers[1]],translate[RanNumbers[2]],translate[RanNumbers[3]],translate[RanNumbers[4]], translate[RanNumbers[5]], correctAns);*/


//Create dynamic select menu
document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent = foreignWords[number];
var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
for (var i = 0; i < RanNumbers.length; i++) {
        guess += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";
}
guess += '<option value="6">' + correctAns + '</option>';
guess += "</select>";

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = guess;
numGuessed = document.getElementById('guesses').value;

function arrayValueIndex(arr, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === val) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var numGames = 5;
var numGuesses = 1;
var correct = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var prevNumber;


var guessedList = new Array(6);
var correctList = new Array(6);
var wordGenerated = new Array(6);
//On click, gather correct and wrong answers, create new numbers, create new options, create new word.
document.getElementById('submitAns').onclick = function () {

var counter = 0;


    
    prevNumber = number;
    number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30)),
    output = '',
    correctAns = translate[number];
    document.getElementById('numGuess').innerHTML = "Question #" + numGuesses;
    
     var
    genWord = document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent,
        select = document.getElementById('guesses'),
        selectedText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    prevNumber === arrayValueIndex(translate, selectedText) ? correct++ : wrong++;

    //Re doing the function, getting new values...
    function wordGen() {
        for (var j = 0; j < RanNumbers.length; j++) {
            var temp = 0;
            do {
                temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
            RanNumbers[j] = temp;

        }
    }

    //Call the previous function
    wordGen();

    //Create dynamic select menu
    document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent = foreignWords[number];
    var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        guess += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";
    }
    guess += '<option value="6">' + correctAns + '</option>';
    guess += "</select>";

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = guess;
    numGuessed = document.getElementById('guesses').value;

    function arrayValueIndex(arr, val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] === val) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Checking of the answers below, Accumilating correct and wrong answer. 
    numGuesses++;
for( counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
{
    wordGenerated[counter] = foreignWords[number];
    guessedList[counter] = document.getElementById('guesses').options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    correctList[counter] = translate[number];
}   
   
    if (numGuesses == 6) {
        document.getElementById('generatedWord').innerHTML = "<span style='font-size:12px;color:red';>Please click for a new game when ready!</span><br /><p>You got " + wrong + " questions wrong " + "<br />You got " + correct + " questions correct";
            $('#submitAns').hide();
            for(var d=0;d<6;d++){
                alert('Generated word: ' + wordGenerated[d] + '  Guessed Word: ' + guessedList[d] + '  Correct Word: ' + correctList[d]);   
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the point of that switch statement? All the cases do the same thing.

Comment: You can use a cookie to store the selected option. The cookie will be triggered on clicking the Check button.

Comment: I commented out the switch statement, it still locked up. The `for( ; counter < 6; )` is an infinite loop, because you don't increment `counter` in the loop.

Comment: Why is the question tagged jquery, but you use plain Javascript instead of jQuery?

Comment: @Barmar Because I thought jquery could be a solution to the problem

Comment: @Barmar I've fixed it up. It will now store the first FRENCH WORD, ENGLISH WORD, AND THE WORD THEY GUESSED. But it will not store any others.. Please run my updated fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesw1/w8p7b6p3/9/   I also edited my question

Answer (score 0):

So I have worked out how to:

1. Store the users guess for each answer
2. Store the generated french word ( The word you need to guess the english of )
3. Store the correct word for each iteration of the game ( Runs 5 times )

What I have changed:

1. I have taken out the for loop I was using to add to the arrays
2. I have declared the counter variable outside the .click function so it doesn't revert back to 0 each time the user guesses...

Feel free to look at my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesw1/w8p7b6p3/11/

#### I achieved this by adding the following code:

```
  //I also Declared the counter variable outside the .click function so that it won't revert back to 0 everytime the user guesses.
 counter++;
//This has been added to keep adding the following details to each array.
    wordGenerated[counter] = foreignWords[number];
    guessedList[counter] = document.getElementById('guesses').options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    correctList[counter] = translate[number];
 
//This was already there, It just alerts the details of the users guesses (guessed, correct and french word
    if (numGuesses == 6) {
        document.getElementById('generatedWord').innerHTML = "<span style='font-size:12px;color:red';>Please click for a new game when ready!</span><br /><p>You got " + wrong + " questions wrong " + "<br />You got " + correct + " questions correct";
            $('#submitAns').hide();
            for(var d=0;d<wordGenerated.length;d++){
                alert('Generated word: ' + wordGenerated[d] + '  Guessed Word: ' + guessedList[d] + '  Correct Word: ' + correctList[d]);   
            }
    }
};
```